# How to aggregate data with slowly changing dimension

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I will try to explain my problem with a ridiculous english level and a very hard situation to explain.

On Teradata, I have a first table table1 with SCD2 changing (slowly changing dimension), so each record have a start and end date.

[image: Dataset]

I want to create new table (table2) with all columns except one (non-useful) from table1. And obviously without this column I have duplicate lines so I group by all other columns, and calculate min(startdate) and max(enddate) to recreate historical records. So i want result like this :

[image: Expected results]

But the only result i can return is like this :

```
select Key, UsefulData, min(EtartDate), max(EndDate)
from table1
group by Key, UsefulData
```

[image: Actual results]

With this kind of result, if I want to analyse situation at January 30, 2 lines came back (UsefulData = 1 and = 0), but the truth is UsefulData = 1.

How can I create my table 2 from dataset table 1 please ?

Precisions : StartDate of NextRow always EndDate+1 of current row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teradata supports [syntax](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/yxJhWt7vS29cXqr2xub_VA/QB2oV2_1gDaHQtoF9QabnA) to do exactly what you want, but it works on Periods only. Luckily your StartDate & EndDate can be ccombined into a Period using `period(StartDate, EndDate+1)` (start is included, but end excluded in Standard SQL):

```
select NORMALIZE Key, UsefulData, period(StartDate, EndDate+1) as pd
from table1
```

If you want to split it back into two separate columns:

```
select Key, UsefulData, 
   begin(pd) as StartDate, 
   last(pd) as EndDate -- reverts the +1
from
 (
   select NORMALIZE Key, UsefulData, period(StartDate, EndDate) as pd
   from table1
 ) as dt
```

There's also a [normalized table](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/bRuJvlj3g0VsfPxgT_G%7Eng/IqSBi8isYZft5FRq2jc0Mw), but again, only for Periods.

Answer (score 1):

This reads as a gaps-and-island problem. You want to group togethers "adjacent" records that have the same `key` and `usefuldata`.

Here is one approach that uses the difference between row numbers to define the groups, then aggregation:

```
select key, usefuldata, min(startdate) startdate, max(enddate) enddate
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by key order by startdate) rn1
        row_number() over(partition by key, usefuldata order by startdate) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by key, usefuldata, rn1 - rn2
```

It is a bit complicated to explain how this works. You can run the subquery first, and see how the difference between the row numbers changes when a new group starts.

Comment: Thank you, first I have now a term to search for this kind of problem, and there is a lot to read.

I'm just afraid the solution will not work regards to the huge volume of my table. I have 1.3 billion lines, i know that expected lines will be around 115 millions. For now i have "no more spool space" when i'm running the query but i have a good start now to search and find my answer. Thanks.